# Howto setup device-node for a platform-device

Tags: device-tree

In my world **I do not have a devicetree**, but I have a third-party kernel-module for some part of HW that relies on a device-tree.

This is the third-party module's probe function:

```
static int foo_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    ...
    struct foo_device *foo;
    struct device_node *np = pdev->dev.of_node;
    ...
    if (np) {
          const struct of_device_id *match;
          match = of_match_node(foo_of_ids, np);
          if (match && match->data) {
              foo->data = match->data;
          }
    }
    ....
}
```

I know how to implement a 'stub-driver' that registers a platform-device so that my third-party module get's probed. And I have a further requirement, this stub-driver has to be build out of kernel-tree.

But I don't know how to setup properly the 'struct device_node *np' for my platform-device to simulate a non existing tree (of_root on my system is NULL). Any help welcome!